# the trait cannot be made into an object because method `merge` references the `Self` type in this parameter - rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an undo/redo system for my app via the [undo](https://github.com/evenorog/undo/blob/master/src/lib.rs) crate. I want a globally accessible `HISTORY`
variable to which I can push `Box<dyn Action>` trait objects.

```
use undo::{Action, History};

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref HISTORY: History<Box<dyn Action<Output = (), Error = String, Target = AppState>>> = History::new();
}
```

This gives error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Action` cannot be made into an object
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
   --> C:\Users\Primary User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\undo-0.46.0\src\lib.rs:135:8
    |
135 |     fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut Self) -> Merged {
    |        ^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because method `merge` references the `Self` type in this parameter
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Here's the problem trait [`Action`](https://github.com/evenorog/undo/blob/ab356382c2d62aec57e21d236109288c05ae17bb/src/lib.rs), from the undo library source code:

```rust
pub trait Action {
    /// The target type.
    type Target;
    /// The output type.
    type Output;
    /// The error type.
    type Error;

    /// Applies the action on the target and returns `Ok` if everything went fine,
    /// and `Err` if something went wrong.
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut Self::Target) -> Result<Self>;

    /// Restores the state of the target as it was before the action was applied
    /// and returns `Ok` if everything went fine, and `Err` if something went wrong.
    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut Self::Target) -> Result<Self>;

    /// Reapplies the action on the target and return `Ok` if everything went fine,
    /// and `Err` if something went wrong.
    ///
    /// The default implementation uses the [`apply`](trait.Action.html#tymethod.apply) implementation.
    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut Self::Target) -> Result<Self> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    /// Used for manual merging of actions.
    fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut Self) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}
```

Comment: If you implement `Action` for `struct MyAction`, the `merge` function for it requires that the parameter be a `&mut MyAction`, but if you have a `dyn Action`, it cannot ensure this so it is not object safe. Could you accept a `&mut dyn Action` instead?

Comment: @kmdreko Did you mean to change the `merge` function signature in the `Action` trait, maybe it is not possible, since `undo` is a third-party crate he wants to import.

Comment: @kmdreko That's not why, is it? The other `&mut self` functions are fine. The issue is that `merge` requires "the *other* argument shall be the same type as *this* object", which is apparently not something that Rust can figure out at runtime when all it has are `dyn Action`s (I suppose it's the same issue as trying to implement double dispatch with vtables). [See here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78a8eec7be5d75e6454d12f7ad8b2ded)

Comment: @HTNW yes, my apologies for not being clear, I was referring to the second parameter. And I missed the part that this is from a library, so changing `merge()` is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to create a history that can contain different types of `Action`, but this is not how `undo` is meant to be used. The type for which you implement `Action` is intended to represent all possible actions in the history, so if there are multiple kinds you would typically implement `Action` on an `enum` to represent this. If the reason you want to use a trait object is simply to avoid `match` statements in the all methods of your `Action` impl, I would recommend using the crate `enum_dispatch` to generate this boilerplate for you. However, if you have a very good reason to use a trait instead of an enum (i.e. you need the set of actions in your app to be extensible by other code), then the trait object approach can be made to work, though it will be more complicated, a little slower, and less readable. I have illustrated both possible solutions below:

## Using `enum_dispatch`

`enum_dispatch` simply automatically implements a trait for an enum composed of types that implement that trait. In order to use it to create a type you can implement `Action` for, you would create your own trait `AppAction` that is just like `undo::Action`, except that the return types are fixed and the second argument of `merge` takes the enum type rather than `Self`, like so:

```
#[enum_dispatch(AppActionEnum)]
pub trait AppAction {
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut AppActionEnum) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}

#[enum_dispatch]
pub enum AppActionEnum {
    MyAction1,
    MyAction2,
    ...
}

impl Action for AppActionEnum {
    type Target = AppState;
    type Output = ();
    type Error = String;

    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::apply(self, target)
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::undo(self, target)
    }

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::redo(self, target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, other: &mut AppActionEnum) -> Merged {
        AppAction::merge(self, other)
    }
}
```

With this solution, you can implement `AppAction::merge` for a particular concrete type by matching on the second argument for types that can merge with `Self` and using `_ => Merged::No` to ignore everything else.

## Using a trait object and `as_any`

If you would still like to use dynamic dispatch, just like before you can create your own trait `AppAction`, but this time make the argument of `merge` a trait object, and implement `undo::Action` for boxes of that type.

```
pub trait AppAction {
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, _: &mut dyn AppAction) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}

impl Action for Box<dyn AppAction> {
    type Target = AppState;
    type Output = ();
    type Error = String;
    
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.deref_mut().apply(target);
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.deref_mut().undo(target);
    }

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.deref_mut().redo(target);
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, other: &mut Box<dyn MyAction>) -> Merged {
        self.deref_mut().merge(other.deref_mut());
    }
}
```

However, now comes the question of how to actually implement the `merge` method when you don't know the concrete type of the other action. For this, you will have to use `Any` to attempt to downcast to each concrete type the action could be merged with. Ideally, this would be as simple as using `&mut dyn MyAction + Any` in `merge` and `Box<dyn MyAction + Any>` in your `History`, however Rust does not support compound trait objects at present. There is a somewhat involved workaround based on making `Any` a supertrait of your trait, but you would be better off using the crate [`as_any`](https://docs.rs/as-any/0.2.0/as_any/) to handle this for you. Once you make `as_any::AsAny` a supertrait of `AppAction` and impl `as_any::Downcast` for `dyn AppAction`, you can write a merge implementation like so:

```
fn merge(&mut self, other: &mut dyn MyAction) -> Merged {
    if let Some(other) = other.downcast_mut::<MyOtherAction1>() {
         // handle actions of type MyOtherAction1
         return Merged::Yes // or Merged::Annul if appropriate
    }
    if let Some(other) = other.downcast_mut::<MyOtherAction2>() {
         // handle actions of type MyOtherAction2
         return Merged::Yes // or Merged::Annul if appropriate
    }
    // and so on for all the other types this action can merge with...
    Merged::No
}
```

Again, this option is by far the more confusing of the two, so only use it if you really need to.

Comment: Is there anything special you need to do get  ```enum_dispatch``` working? I get error ```unsppported argument type```. Tested with version ```0.3.5```. Also is ```Merged::No``` a custom enum we implement or something to do with ```itertools::structs::merge```?

Comment: edit I see that merge is exported from ```undo```: ```use undo::{Merged, Action, History}```

Comment: Got enum_dispatch working by enabling ```#![feature(proc_macro)]```

Comment: @ANimator120 Yeah, `Merged` is from `undo`. Not sure why `enum_dispatch` would give that error, though. It shouldn't require any nightly features if you are on an up-to-date stable version. You can always ask another question if you have more trouble with it.

Comment: Turns out the ```_``` in ```AppAction::merge``` was the problem. Issue: https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch/-/issues/44

Comment: But as a follow up, I have this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276714/method-merge-has-an-incompatible-type-for-trait-rust-undo-redo

Comment: @ANimator120 Ah, my bad, that's a typo. I've fixed the signature in the answer.

Comment: So in my original question I was trying to create a lazy global state,  is ```HISTORY``` now of type ```History<AppActionEnum>``` or is it of type ```History<<Box<dyn AppAction>>```? Either type yields error ```(dyn FnMut(Signal) + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely```.

Comment: @ANimator120 Assuming you went for the `enum_dispatch` solution, it's the former. As for the other error, it's because of the second type parameter on `History`, which defaults to `Box<dyn FnMut(Signal)>`. To share it across threads, you'll probably need to change this to `Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send>`, maybe `Sync` as well.

Comment: Yes, ```Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>``` was needed. If we have a complex ```AppState```, aren't we going to want to provide associated types to our ```AppAction``` trait, so that we don't need to borrow our entire ```self``` when mutating ```AppState```?

Comment: @ANimator120 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Could you post a question explaining what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes, here's a new post with a more detailed explanation of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312200/issues-providing-type-information-to-trait-implementers