# Issues Providing Type information to Trait Implementers

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a globally accessible undo/redo functionality in my Rust app via the [undo crate](https://github.com/evenorog/undo).
Additionally I am using [enum_dispatch](https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch) to handle the dynamic dispatch of my `dyn AppActions`, such as `AddName` or `AddPhoneNumber`.

However I'm running into the issue of needing to mutably borrow `self` more than once when I want to add a phone number or add a name to state. This is because I need to mutate some field of my state (`names` or `phone_numbers`) to add some data, and I need to mutate `history` so we have a record of these changes which can be undone/redone.But this leads me to mutably borrowing our state twice, once for the history, and once for whatever field we're wanting to add data to. Now I know one solutions to this problem, as discussed [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/borrowing-issue-trying-to-avoid-redundancy/15817), is borrowing specific fields from `self`, rather then the whole `self`. But for this approach to work we need to provide our `AppAction` implementers with some type attributes, so that when we pass them into `self.history.apply()`, we can also pass in `self.names` or `self.phone_numbers`, which have types `Vec<String>` and `Vec<i32>`, respectively.

This sounds simple enough, but as it's unclear to me how to do this given the limitations of `enum_dispatch`. I thought that I could add associated types to `AppAction` , similar to the way `undo::Action` has associated types`Target`,`Output`, and `Error`. So for `AddName`, `Target=Vec<String>` and for `AddPhoneNumber` `Targe=Vec<i32>`. But for reasons described [in this issue](https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch/-/issues/38), enum_dispatch does not allow you to add associated types to your trait definition. Is there some other way to add these type arguments to my `AppAction` implementers, `AddName` and `AddPhoneNumber`?

In the referenced issue, OP mentions:

> I should wrap the associated type in another enum. Maybe it's not
> necessary for enum_dispatch to provide a general solution. Users
> should customize themselves. I'll close the issue.

However I'm not really sure what they mean by this or how to apply this to my particular case. Dopes OP suggest that we have some Enum, `AppActionType` as `Target` instead of `AppState`? Or is OP essentially suggesting not to use `enum_dispatch` for cases where implementer methods need differently typed values?

If anyone would like to play with the actual code, I put it in this [repo](https://github.com/wyhinton/enum_dispatch_issue).

```rust
use undo::{Action, History, Merged, Signal, record::Builder};
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;
use std::sync::Mutex;

//create lazy mutex for globally accesible state
lazy_static::lazy_static!{
    static ref APP_STATE: Mutex<AppState> = Mutex::new(AppState::new());
}

pub struct AppState{
    names: Vec<String>,
    phone_numbers: Vec<i32>,
    history: History<AppActionEnum, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>
}

impl AppState{
    pub fn new()->Self{
         let build = Builder::new()
             .limit(100)
             .capacity(100)
             .connect(Box::new(|s| { dbg!(s); }) as _)
             .build::<AppActionEnum>();
        
        AppState{
            names: vec![],
            history: History::from(build),
            phone_numbers: vec![],
        }
    }
    //Now I need to mutate self.names, and self.history, but history.apply will only accept type AppState
    pub fn add_name(&mut self, name: String){
        self.history.apply(self, AppActionEnum::DoAddName(AddName("testing yes".to_string())));
    }
    pub fn add_phone_number(&mut self, phone_number: i32){
        self.history.apply(self, AppActionEnum::DoAddPhoneNumber(AddPhoneNumber("testing yes".to_string())));
    }
}

//enums for dynamic dispatch
#[enum_dispatch]
pub enum AppActionEnum {
    DoAddName(AddName),
    DoAddPhoneNumber(AddPhoneNumber)
}


#[enum_dispatch(AppActionEnum)]
pub trait AppAction: Send + Sync{
    //type Taget <--associated type which would allow us to
    //mutably borrow single fields of AppState, instead of the entire AppState,
    //however enum_dispatch does not allow associated types
    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;
    // fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut Target) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String>;
    // fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut Target) -> Result<(), String>;

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut Target) -> Result<(), String> {
    // fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.apply(target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, test: &mut AppActionEnum) -> Merged {
        Merged::No
    }
}

pub struct AddName(String);

impl AppAction for AddName{
    //Target = Vec<String>
    //..apply()/undo()/redo()/merge()..
}

pub struct AddPhoneNumber(i32);
impl AppAction for AddPhoneNumber{
    //Target = Vec<i32>
    //..apply()/undo()/redo()/merge()..
}

//Wrapper around undo::Action
impl Action for AppActionEnum {
    type Target = AppState;
    type Output = ();
    type Error = String;

    fn apply(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::apply(self, target)
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::undo(self, target)
    }

    fn redo(&mut self, target: &mut AppState) -> Result<(), String> {
        AppAction::redo(self, target)
    }

    fn merge(&mut self, other: &mut AppActionEnum) -> Merged {
        AppAction::merge(self, other)
    }
} 


fn main(){
    dbg!("running");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can just implement the enums yourself instead of using `enum_dispatch`, and add the associated types you need? After all, `enum_dispatch` is just a convenient crate, it AFAIK doesn't do anything you couldn't do yourself. (And if you have a lot of repetition, you can create your own custom declarative macros to define the types. They will be less general than what is offered by `enum_dispatch`, but they'll do the job for you.)

Comment: @user4815162342 I see. True, ```enum_dispatch``` is just a convenience crate, but I was hoping it could help me quickly get over writing a lot of boiler plate. But maybe there's alternative to the approach I've described that would let me keep ```enum_dispatch``` and still have the type data. In the issue that I referenced, do you think OP had basically opted to write custom solutions rather instead of  ```enum_dispatch```?

Comment: That's how I understood it, yes, but I haven't studied the issue deeply, so my understanding may be off. My point is just that as long as you have an actual solution you can write manually, most of your problem is already solved. You can use the simple `macro_rules!` macros to write your own convenience layer which won't be as powerful as `enum_dispatch`, but will do nicely to eliminate your particular boilerplate. Sure, it'd be nicer if it just worked with `enum_dispatch`, but such is life. Hopefully someone else will be able to provide more concrete advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some reason the application of an action would need access to the `History`, why not just use two `struct`s, one to represent the current application state, and one that augments this with history?

```
pub struct CurrentState {
    names: Vec<String>,
    phone_numbers: Vec<i32>,
}

pub struct AppState {
    current: CurrentState,
    history: History<AppActionEnum, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>,
}

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref APP_STATE: Mutex<AppState> = Mutex::new(AppState::new());
}
```

If you change the type of `Target` in your `Action` impl and in the methods of `AppAction` from `AppState` to `CurrentState`, then you can implement a method like `add_name` on `AppState` like this:

```
pub fn add_name(&mut self, name: String) {
    self.history.apply(
       self.current, 
       AppActionEnum::DoAddName(AddName("testing yes".to_string()))
    );
}
```

Grouping together fields that might need to be accessed together in their own `struct` is common practice for exactly this reason in Rust, so much so that there is a name for this pattern: [Splitting Borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html). Usually if you needs to promise to the compiler that two borrows of the same structure are disjoint, this pattern is what you should reach for.

If you'd like, you can even implement `Deref<Target=CurrentState>` and `DerefMut` for `AppState` so that any methods and fields on `CurrentState` are automatically available on a reference to an `AppState`.